# mxnet: when using an RNN in model, model initializer crashes with context of multuple GPUs

Tags: python, gpu, mxnet

I am new to `mxnet` and running a script lightly modified from the documentation on [RNN with gluon](https://gluon.mxnet.io/chapter05_recurrent-neural-networks/rnns-gluon.html). I modified the code so that I am working with strictly numerical time series rather than an NLP problem. Everything was running great until I modified this line:

```
context = mx.gpu()
```

to

```
GPU_COUNT = 3
context = [mx.gpu(i) for i in range(GPU_COUNT)]
```

now the variable initialization triggers an error that causes a crash, in particular at this line:

```
model.collect_params().initialize(mx.init.Xavier(), ctx=context)
```

The line causes this error:

```
mxnet.base.MXNetError: include/mxnet/./base.h:388: Invalid context string[]
```

I have only been using `mxnet` for a few days, so I am not very knowledgeable about what could go wrong. However, I have run another sample script - for an MLP - where I also swapped in multiple gpus for a single one, and that ran fine.

This made me think that it is the RNN, and indeed when I removed the RNN portion of the code (so that it's just essentially a feed forward network) it runs the troublesome line just fine with any valid number of GPUs. Also, I tried both with a 'rnn_relu' option and a 'gru' option, and they both failed with the same error.

So my question is: **do `mxnet` RNNs work with multuple GPUs (one machine) in `mxnet` currently via the gluon API?** I don't see this discussed one way or the other in the docs, although I have seen some discussions on [github](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/9344) as to certain functions not being implemented for multi device use. How would I confirm this theory? Also are there other explanations I should be checking into?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can train RNNs across multiple GPU (and multiple machines) in MXNet. I just confirmed the code below works with MXNet v1.3.0 on a machine with 4 GPUs.

```
import mxnet as mx

GPU_COUNT = 4
context = [mx.gpu(i) for i in range(GPU_COUNT)]

model = mx.gluon.rnn.RNN(hidden_size=10, num_layers=1)
model.collect_params().initialize(mx.init.Xavier(), ctx=context)
```

You might want to double check that nothing is overriding your context, since it looks like you're using an empty context here (i.e. `string[]`). You'll also get a similar error when trying to create an array on multiple contexts at the same time.

```
mx.nd.zeros(shape=(10,10), ctx=context)
```

Gives the following error (notice the context contains multiple devices):

```
MXNetError: [20:15:03] include/mxnet/./base.h:388: Invalid context string [gpu(0), gpu(1), gpu(2), gpu(3)]
```